# what i should use && or ||

Tags: php, if-statement

Here is my code

```
<?php

if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']!="/index.php?task=join&" || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']!="/index.php?task=join&step=1" 
|| $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']!="/index.php?task=join&step=2" ) {
    include ("inc/js/script.php");
}

?>
```

I need to say "if REQUEST_URI != /index.php?task=join& 'or' /index.php?task=join&step=1 'or' /index.php?task=join&step=2 >>> include inc/js/script.php

When i use && it work correctly but i think the correctly answer should be ||

What is the wrong please ?

Comment: Ever heard of [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like you want "AND" - or you could change the sense of it all into:

```
if (! (uri == first || uri == second || uri == third) )
```

If you think about it, the URI can't be both "/index.php?task=join&" *and* "/index.php?task=join&step=1", so it must be unequal to *one* of them - so using `||` in your current code will *always* return true.

Answer (score 2):

`||` means `or`, `&&` means `and`. If `or` is what you're going for, use `||`.

However, if you use `||`, the condition will always evaluate to `true`, since `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will always be either different from `"/index.php?task=join&"` or `"/index.php?task=join&step=1"`, since it can't be both.

So I think you're actually looking for an `and` condition - `&&`.

Also, you should use [`strcmp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) for string comparison.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is `&&` because you want it to be `AND` as you are comparing the **same variable** is **not equal** to different values.

You want the variable to be `not this, not that, *AND* not the other`.

If it uses `OR` (`||`), then it is allowed to be one of them, but as long as it is not all of them (which it obviously can't be).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you want :
I would suggest using $_GET and doing it like this :

```
<?php
 if ($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] == "/index.php" && $_GET['task'] == "join" && (isset($_GET['step'] && ($_GET['step'] == 1 || $_GET['step'] == 2)))
 include_once("inc/js/script.php");



?>
```

Comment: Like Salman A's proposal, this is flawed because it allows other request parameters to be present, whereas the original code doesn't

Answer (score 1):

Your English description of what you want to do is fine, but when you get to code, there's a translation error.

Here's the behavior you said you want:

> if REQUEST_URI != /index.php?task=join& 'or'
>   /index.php?task=join&step=1 'or' /index.php?task=join&step=2 >>>
>   include inc/js/script.php

When you put it that way, it's clear that the "not" (the ! in !=) applies to all the URIs.  So lets break out that NOT and use brackets to indicate that it applies to everything:

> if not (REQUEST_URI = /index.php?task=join& 'or'
>   /index.php?task=join&step=1 'or' /index.php?task=join&step=2) >>>
>   include inc/js/script.php

Now to get us from English to near-code we just need to spell things out a bit more completely:

```
if ! (REQUEST_URI == /index.php?task=join& or
        REQUEST_URI == /index.php?task=join&step=1 or
        REQUEST_URI == /index.php?task=join&step=2) 
    include inc/js/script.php
```

This is essentially the solution Jon Skeet proposed.

As a further note, here's why your code works if you change the ||s to &&s.  You've essentially rediscovered a well know rule of logic called De Morgan's law (referred to in Salman A's comment), which has two forms (where "<==>" means "if and only if"):

1. !(A || B)  <==> !A && !B
2. !(A && B)  <==> !A || !B

According to form 1 of De Morgan's law, the code above is therefore the same as

```
if (!REQUEST_URI == /index.php?task=join& and
        !REQUEST_URI == /index.php?task=join&step=1 and
        !REQUEST_URI == /index.php?task=join&step=2) 
    include inc/js/script.php
```

which is the same as

```
if (REQUEST_URI != /index.php?task=join& and
        REQUEST_URI != /index.php?task=join&step=1 and
        REQUEST_URI != /index.php?task=join&step=2) 
    include inc/js/script.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the request uri to be:

a) Not equal to any of those things (&&)

or

b) Not equal to one or more (or all) of those things (||)

You want && I suspect.